# All link not working

Tags: wordpress

I just moved my local website to my online server like always but all links are 404, even style.css

Everything is on my server but no links are working through http.

I redo everything 4 times…

All my links are relative like /wp-content/themes/theme-name/img/img.svg

Everything is hardcodded, I don't use the post function.

Absolute links are not working either.

Comment: Did you update your home/site URLs? Also, go to settings > permalinks and click save to update those.

Comment: Yes I did it but I don't really use it as it's just a onepage website entirely hardcodded.

Comment: Hi @tomdes, Please check your files and folder permissions on server.
This may cause if permission are not correct. use 755 for folders and 644 for files

Comment: Thanks, I think it was something like this because I just change the name of the theme folder and it resolved the problem.